# Authenticated access required : SOAP webservice + Liferay

Tags: soap, liferay, soapui

I am exposing SOAP webservice from my custom portlet. I was able to generate and tried accessing the service from external application, it works fine.
But when i was tested the service from SOAP UI, it throws
java.rmi.RemoteException: Authenticated access required
. If i add AccessController annotation before my method of ServiceImpl as below, I can access from SOAP UI. But i cannot add this below annotation as it can be accessible without credential.

@AccessControlled(guestAccessEnabled=true)

I want to access my custom web service from SOAP UI? why it is throwing Authenticated access required even i add valid userName and Password of Liferay for the service while invoking? Any guess?

[image]

Comment: It got resolved. In SOAP UI authorization section, you should provide as follows:
In Authentication and Security Relative settings of SOAP UI, give these configurations. 
1.  User Credential : Liferay Username (screenname) and password
2.  Domain : ""
    -    Pre-emptive auth: "Authenticate pre-emptively"
    -    Outgoing WSS : ""
    -    Incoming WSS : ""